# plot a pie chart next to a bar chart and have it use all the space

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, bar-chart, pie-chart

I'm trying to plot a 2x2 grid of subplots but of different types. When I have a bar chart and a pie chart on the same row, if the bar chart have long axe labels, the labels will use all the space and the bars will be small, that's fine. But the pie chart on the same row will adjust its size to the bars. How do I make it use all the vertical space?

I have simplified my case with a single row of 2 plots, but the final version has 2 rows and plots in the same column don't necessarily have the same width, which is why I'm using add_gridspec instead of a simple subplots(2,2). Here is the code (thanks chat GPT for providing the sample data).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set the seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Define the list of countries
countries = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Germany', 'France', 'Japan', 'Australia', 'Brazil', 'India', 'China', 'Mexico']

# Add a country with a long name
countries.append('United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland')

# Define the list of possible statuses
statuses = ['Active', 'Inactive', 'Error', 'Warning']

# Generate random data
data = {
    'Country': np.random.choice(countries, 500),
    'Status': np.random.choice(statuses, 500)
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained", figsize=(10, 8))

gs0 = fig.add_gridspec(1, 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1])

# Plot the data
df.reset_index().pivot_table('index', 'Country', 'Status', aggfunc='count').plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

s = df.Status.value_counts()
s.plot.pie(ax=ax2)
```

And here is what I'm getting:

[image: result]

Comment: `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, layout="constrained", figsize=(10, 8))` is more concise than adding subplots with Gridspec. Height and width ratios can be adjusted with `width_ratios=` and `height_ratios=` in `.subplot`. This is an FYI, not an answer to your question.

Comment: The first order of data analytics is typically to clean the data. As such, if you have a long category, relative to other categories, it should be edited, manually or with something like `textwrap` (e.g. `countries.append('\n'.join(textwrap.wrap('United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', width=18)))`).  A data visualization should be ordered, and easy to quickly digest, long text descriptions are contrary to that objective.

Comment: You want the pie chart to be central alignment vertically?

Comment: Pie plots are not the most effective ways to communicate data because the eye/brain is better at comparing lengths and heights. As such, it is better to use a bar plot than a pie plot. Also, stacked bars are more difficult to read. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMTWA.png) also see [Data Visualization: Rules for Encoding Values in Graph](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/b-eye/encoding_values_in_graph.pdf)